issue with connecting a specific stored procedure to Power App
If I want to add a new connection to a Power App, I can add every stored procedure directly except one. For that specific procedure, the loading spinner keeps spinning, and the procedure does not show up.
I have tried the following:
Recreating the stored procedure
Repeatedly attempting to integrate it into the Power App
Restarting the App

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi I had the same problem, make sure all column names are different. The procedure will not return an error, but the application will not add it
